# Inline function returning statically created object

Tags: c++, function, static, inline

```
inline Config& config()
{
    static Config *c = new Config();
    return *c;
}
```

The function above returns a pointer to class Config, created once when function calls.

Will the C++ compiler be able to inline this function correctly?

I mean `c` is static object, and creating it at first time will lead to inlined `new Config()` somewhere in the code. But when the function is called second time, what will be at the place of the `config()`? Inlined c? Or a function call?

Comment: I see no reason why the function should be any less inlinable than any other function (of course inline is still only a hint, not a requirement), and the static variable will behave as you would expect, too (the standard requires that --> 7.1.2.4).

Comment: Please note that your function has a memory leak because the object you create will never get freed. Declare `c` as a `Config` instead of a `Config*`, or use a smart-pointer class, and it will get destroyed as your program terminates.

Comment: Both solutions potentially introduce issues with the order objects are destructed.  This method is the simplest way of ensuring an object remains alive as long as needed, provided `Config`'s destructor doesn't do anything important, and your target system reliably frees resources when the program terminates.

Comment: This is somewhat orthogonal to the actual question, but in MSVC6 (I know it's old) it can be inlined, and if both inline and non-inline calls exist in the application the static local will get constructed TWICE, once at the first inlined call and once at the first non-inlined call. I presume this bug is fixed in later versions but I never confirmed.

Comment: Rob Kennedy: thank you for pointing the leak out. I will use static creation instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a slight misunderstanding about how such static variables work.  It seems like you're thinking the compiler emits one set of code the first time the function is called, and another set every other time.  That's not the case.  You might consider the following transformation.

```
bool initialized = false;
Config* c;

inline Config& config() {
    if(!initialized) {
        c = new Config();
        initialized = true;
    }
    return *c;
}
```

That's a simplification, but it gets the point across.  The function tracks whether or not the static has been initialized, and if it hasn't, does so.  It does this check every time you call the function.

With that in mind, the existance of a static variable has no direct impact on the inlinability of a particular function... the compiler will simply inline the check along with everything else.  The question is simply, does this new expanded code still meet the requirements the compiler sets forth for inlining a function?  It might not, but either way the visible result should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the compiler, but from what I've seen in MSVC, it'll inline two globals to do this (at an assembly level). one is a bool to indicate if the static var was inited, and the other for the actual static var your setting.

however, one should note that `inline` is more a hint these days, so the function might not ever get inlined, just cause the compiler decided that inline the constructor for the the object and the static handling code would cause too much bloat etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the inliner couldn't handle such trivial cases as this, no functions would ever get inlined at all.

Comment: That's a slight stretch, since the static variable does introduce complexity that could thwart "traditional" inlining.  As it turns out, it doesn't, although it is possible the additional code results in the function failing whatever heuristic the compiler uses to make the call.

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of the dynamic allocation, if I may ask? I would get rid of it:

```
inline Config& config()
{
    static Config c = Config();
    return c;
}
```

If `Config` is not a POD, you can even just say `static Config c;` and get the same semantics.

Comment: Dynamic allocation was just for purpose of showing example. My class Config has it's own default constructor, so static Config c will be ok to. But thanks anyway for pointing that it is a leak, I haven't know about this.